# Specify datetime format for DAG run_id

Tags: airflow

Sometimes AirFlow provides milliseconds in run_id (manual__2023-10-24T06:30:16.239880+00:00), and sometimes doesn't (scheduled__2023-11-01T03:00:00+00:00), is there a way to specify fixed format without milliseconds for run_id?

I tried searching for format option in AriFlow config file, but it seems there is not option for dag run_id format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scheduled DAGs `dag_run_id` is autogenerated and you cannot change it.

For manual triggers you can pass `dag_run_id` parameter to [Trigger a new DAG Run](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_dag_run) endpoint and provide a custom identifier.

> dag_run_id
> string Nullable
>
> Run ID.
>
> The value of this field can be set only when creating the object. If
> you try to modify the field of an existing object, the request fails
> with an BAD_REQUEST error.
>
> If not provided, a value will be generated based on execution_date.
>
> If the specified dag_run_id is in use, the creation request fails with
> an ALREADY_EXISTS error.
>
> This together with DAG_ID are a unique key.